# How to fill texboxes from database when an onClick event happens

Tags: php, arrays

I want my *php* file to fill textboxes with information from the database according to the selected value of a select box tag. And every time the selection changes the textboxes should be re-filled accordingly.

The problem is that when I call a *javascript* method which contains *php* code the page is reloaded and some initial values collected by `$_POST[]` when the page was loaded for the first time are lost.

I want to find a way such that those initial values collected by `$_post[]` are conserved even after the page re-executes the *php*. How can I solve this problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function displaymessagespatient()
{

<?php
    function docmsg()
   { 
    $title = $_POST["title"];
    $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","askthedoctor");
    $sql1="select patient_text from messages where title='".$title."';";
    $sql2="select doctor_text from messages where title='".$title."';";
    $result1=mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
    $result2=mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);
    $row1=mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
    $row2=mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
    return $row1[0];
    } 
     function patmsg()
   { 
    $title = $_POST["title"];
    $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","askthedoctor");
    $sql1="select patient_text from messages where title='".$title."';";
    $sql2="select doctor_text from messages where title='".$title."';";
    $result1=mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
    $result2=mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);
    $row1=mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
    $row2=mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
    return $row2[0];
    } 


  ?>

    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML=docmsg();
    document.getElementById("question").innerHTML=patmsg();         
} 
</script>
</head>


<body>

<?php
if( isset($_POST['username']))
{   
$username=$_POST["username"];
$password=$_POST["password"];
$password=md5($password);
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","askthedoctor");
$sql="select password from login where username='".$username."';";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

if($row[0]!=$password)
{ 
  echo "The username or password that you entered are incorrect!";
  echo "<br/>";
  echo "<a href=\"project_login.php\">Go back to login</a>";
  die();
}

$sql1="select userprivileges from login where username='".$username."';";
$sql2="select image_path from registration1 where id=(select id from login where username='".$username."');"; 
$result1=mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
$result2=mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);
$row1=mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
$row2=mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
$imagepath=$row2[0];
}
if($row1[0]==2)
{
?>

<form  id="patient" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"      action="login.php" >
```

```
<div id="header" class="class_header">
<a href="project_login.php" align="right" color="white">Sign Out</a>
</div>

<div id="body" >
<br/>
<table class="table">
<tr>
<td><font color="white" ><h1 color="white" style="font-size:200%;"  align="center">Welcome <?php echo $username;?></h1></font></td> 
<td> <div id="box"><image height="65px" width="65px" src="<?php echo  $imagepath; ?>"></div></td>
<tr>    
</table>
</div>



<div id="separator" ></div>
<div id="separator" ></div>

<div id="bodyy" style="height: 60%; width: 60%;"  class="div">

<br/><br/><br/>

<fieldset id="registration">
<table class="table">

<tr>
<th>Messages</th>
<?php

$sql="select title from messages where paitient_id=(select id from login where username='".$username."');";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
?>  
<th>Problem Description</th>
<th>Doctor's Answer</th>
<th></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><select name="title"> 
<?php echo "<option value=\"mesazhi1\">".$row[0]."</option>";}?>
</select>
</td>
<td><textarea rows="4" col="50" id ="question" readonly> </textarea></td>
<td><textarea rows="4" col="50" id ="answer" readonly> </textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="openmessage" value="Display Selected Message" onClick="displaymessagespatient()"></td>
<td><input type="button" name="btnSubmit" value="Ask a new question" ></td>
</tr>

</table>
</fieldset>
</div>  
</div>

</form>
<?php } ?>
</body>
```

Comment: I suggest you re-think your approach. For this type of thing I use ajax, and get the javascript to contact a separate php page for database info when needed. Then the javascript can sort out the data and arrange it into the html. This means the page doesnt need reloading and its faster and looks nicer, plus theres no problem with what your having trouble with.

Comment: This won't work because you are mixing javascript with PHP. You need a PHP file to return stuff to javascript via ajax. PHP only outputs server calculations to the client. Then it finishes executing. Ajax will run the php again and get the results and do the job

Comment: Look up for some Ajax tutorials on the internet, there are thousands of them :)